# Git workflow tips

Tags: git, github, msysgit

I started using git and have been using it for couple of months now, and I am curious if my workflow is correct. I work from two different places on the project. here are the stages of my workflow:

1. I pull the project from remote repo
2. make a local branch for a new feature
3. make changes and commit
4. merge the branch with master
5. push to the remote

is this correct way of working on the project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Amber said :

> First, let's just make something clear: there is no single "correct"
>   workflow for Git. There are merely workflows that work - and
>   specifically, workflows that work for you.

There is a good post on a blog about a good git workflow :

[A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

You should read this post, it's really cool and you can adapt the workflow to your needs.
In a nutshell, the workflow proposed by the blog post schematized like this :

[image: A successful git branching model]

I have adopted this workflow for a while. I try to always respect the workflow, whether it's a teamwork or working alone.

Answer (score 6):

First, let's just make something clear: there is no single "correct" workflow for Git. There are merely workflows that *work* - and specifically, workflows that work *for you*.

The workflow you have outlined is typically referred to as a "feature branch" workflow (where you create a branch to work on a given feature/fix/whatever, and then merge it back), and is a perfectly legitimate workflow.

If you only ever work on a single feature at a time, you could choose to simply commit directly to master, then push the updated version. This becomes difficult, however, if you're working on multiple different features simultaneously (whereas a feature branch workflow handles many simultaneous features gracefully).