# Git - Correct way of setting up branches

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a repo that I need to use to deploy the production code of an WebApp to the server. I need advise on what is the correct way of doing it(branching).

I will need 3 branches(I think):

```
- Development
- Quality
- Production
```

Now my doubt is... the "master" branch should be used to the Development or to the Production code?

Best Regards,

Comment: There's no one true answer to this question.

Comment: It depends on you. Personally, I try to follow this branching model http://stackoverflow.com/a/7520761/259576 Maybe it's not appropriate for your use case.

Comment: @SandroMunda I find that model to be great for software release channels, but you can do a little more with webapps as far as deployment goes. As stated in that question, though, there's really no one correct way to do it.

Comment: @Sandro My answer builds on gitflow. Take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the master branch as your main channel, or a preserved state of the working code. That way, if something goes really, really wrong, you can revert back to the master branch. If you're working with an open source project, put the vanilla engine in the master and branch off of that - it will make updating easier in the future.

I'd say keep the branches like they are right now, and sync the servers with their specific branches. That way you can easily merge, push, and pull to your respective servers. That's how  my workflow is, using git-hooks to automatically sync the branches.

Answer (score 1):

The master branch isn't required.  I will delete it sometimes if there isn't an obvious choice.  However, generally you want it to be the branch people are likely to make changes in most frequently, which in this case is the development branch.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how organized your development is, this workflow works for us:

https://plus.google.com/109096274754593704906/posts/R4qkeyRadLR

Also, for the purposes of publishing, rely on scripts to change connection strings and other config values. Smudge/clean scripts could also help. Have a look at progit.org/book, specifically the chapter on git attributes.